# How to change the bootstrap datetimepicker to display only dates and not time

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I have several inputs with dates. I don't need time, but somehow I can't get rid of it.

I tried all the solutions I found on StackOverflow without success.

I am using the tempusdominus datetimepicker.

[JS FIDDLE LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/3dqup7ga/)

Does anyone know how can I remove the option to enter hours and minutes?

I thought `format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'` would do the trick but apparently it's not working.

```
$('#monthDatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: date,
            viewMode: 'days',
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        });
```

Comment: This j Query code makes my eyes hurt. What's the variable for displaying the value in the table? Can you point me to it please ?

Comment: It's the second one `stock[1]`

Comment: Don't use a `datetimepicker` but use a `datepicker` instead?

Comment: You've attempted to set the format, but you've applied it to *nothing*.  `console.log($("#monthDatetimepicker").length)` == 0.  There's nothing with id monthDatetimepicker *at the time you call the options* - nor even after you build the table as it's `monthDatetimepicker0` (etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the *default* options so that it applies to newly created date[time]pickers:

From the [options](https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Options/) page on how to set global defaults:

```
  $.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default = $.extend({}, $.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default, {
    viewMode: 'days',
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
  });
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/negcawoL/)

---

Your issue was that this line

```
$('#monthDatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/dd/YYYY'
```

doesn't get applied to anything as `$('#monthDatetimepicker') === 0` at the time the code runs.

Moving that line to the end also does nothing as your newly created date inputs have `id="monthDatetimepicker" + i`.  Changing to a valid ID such as:

```
$('#monthDatetimepicker0').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/dd/YYYY'
```

then only works for the first picker.

So you could do some hideous `$("[id=^monthDatetimepicker]").datetimepicker...` or, easier, you could add a class into your html builder and use that as a selector.  Or  set it globally as above (which will affect other pickers unless they had a different format applied).  (or use a datepicker instead...)

Answer (score 0):

Add .substring(0,10) at the end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).